# Download a file programmatically while providing feedback to the user using Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a backend which returns a file to be downloaded.

Currently, when the user does something an action is dispatched which runs the reducer `export` and it executes the usual trick to download a file. I'm using redux-toolkit.

```
const mySlice = createSlice({
    name: "my",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        export: (state) => {
            const link = document.createElement("a")
            link.href = '...'

            document.body.appendChild(link)
            link.click()
            link.parentNode?.removeChild(link)
        },
    }
})
```

And this works. However, I would like to provide a feedback to the user while the download is happening, i.e. a modal dialog. So I have defined a `isExporting` property in the state, and there is a component which shows the dialog depending on this property.

However, the reducer written as this does not work:

```
    export: (state) => {
        state.isExporting = true

        const link = document.createElement("a")
        link.href = '...'

        document.body.appendChild(link)
        link.click()
        link.parentNode?.removeChild(link)

        state.isExporting = false
    },
```

because I believe I'm introducing side effects, and moreover the state will be set after the reducer has been executed and not in between.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a async action `createAsyncThunk` and define a extraReducer with cases:

> For this example i create async function download

```
const fakeDownload = async () =>
  new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = "...";
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      link.parentNode?.removeChild(link);

      resolve();
    }, 1000) // I set a timeout to emulate a request.
  );
```

Create async action:

```
export const downloadFile = createAsyncThunk(
  "download/file",
  async (_, thunkApi) => {
    try {
      return fakeDownload();
    } catch (e) {
      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue("Impossible to download");
    }
  }
);
```

The reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  isExporting: false
};

export const appSlice = createSlice({
  name: "app",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(downloadFile.pending, (state) => {
      state.isExporting = true;
    });
    builder.addCase(downloadFile.fulfilled, (state) => {
      state.isExporting = false;
    });
    builder.addCase(downloadFile.rejected, (state) => {
      // Do something with error
      state.isExporting = false;
    });
  }
});

export const isExportingSelector = (state) => state.app.isExporting;

export default appSlice.reducer;
```

Now you can use selector and dispatch action.

You can find a live example here:

[image: Edit goofy-thompson-8bbfc]

Comment: Thanks! Tried it and there's only one thing that is not working: when `click()` is actually executed, I can see in the network tab that the download has been requested, however the promise is immediately resolved. This makes me think that `click()` does not wait for download to be completed. How can the download be awaited so that the promise call `resolve()` after the download has completed?

Comment: @edoedoedo You can share the code of download request ?

Comment: Sure: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-meadow-mx0ln?file=/src/store/slices/app.js
I just edited your function to actually download something. For example with a non existing url, you will see that in the network tab the request lasts some seconds and then will timeout (that is not important of course, what matters is that it takes some seconds) BUT in the console you will see that the promise is immediately fullfilled:

    redux-logger.js:1  action download/file/pending @ 16:53:35.833
    redux-logger.js:1  action download/file/fulfilled @ 16:53:35.846

Comment: If you want to use `link.href` you need to use `setTimeout` to create a fake async function. If you want to fetch file you need to make a fetch request and get data, after it create a link with download data. What you need to download? excel file? txt? image ?

Comment: I'm downloading an excel file, which depending on the request parameters it may take 5-30 seconds, because it is generated on the fly by the backend and the generation takes time. What I would like to have is this: 1) when the user does something the export action is dispatched; 2) the export action should initiate the download in background; 3) until the download actually starts (you see it i.e. in the bottom Chrome bar when it happens) a modal should be shown informing the user that the request is being processed.

Comment: So the modal waiting time should be real (no fake timeout), and it is not important how the download is actually done (I used the href trick but any solution is accepted)

Comment: @edoedoedo Look at function `download` https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-lake-otpp7?file=/src/store/slices/app.js:67-679 I just edit the function

Comment: It works perfectly, exactly as I intended. I also learned something new about how to chain reducers in RTK, thank you so much.